# php strip leading zeros and 0 decimal values

Tags: php, string, floating-point, integer

This falls into the category of 'I'm sure there is a cleaner way to do this' although it works perfectly well. Maybe some kind of function.

I have lists of values such as 
01.0, 
09.5, 
10.0, 
11.5,

I want the values to always exclude the leading 0 and only keep the decimal portion if it it contains a .5. There will never be any other decimal value. My current code is:

```
$data = '09.5'; //just an example value

if (substr($data,0,1) == '0' ) {
    $data = substr($data, 1);
}
if (stripos($data, '.0') !== FALSE ) {
    $data = str_replace('.0','',$data);
}
print $data;
```

Comment: `$data += 0;` will strip the leading zeroes

Comment: You'll want to look at regular expressions and the `preg_replace` function.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just cast it to a float:

```
$data = '09.5';
echo (float) $data; // 9.5

$data = '09.0';
echo (float) $data; // 9

$data = '010';
echo (float) $data;  // 10
```

[Demo](http://codepad.viper-7.com/PgoG89)

You can also use [`floatval()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.floatval.php)

```
echo floatval($data);
```

Comment: I suspect OP's example: *there will never be any other decimal value* makes me think there will be *integer*-like strings with leading zeros. `(float) '010'` is, of course, `8`.

Comment: I was curious about this but http://3v4l.org/INBiF confirms my suspicions that your second example still returns 9.5

Comment: My second example uses `09.0`. It can't return 9.5.